# Google Speech Recognition API output errors, unsure why they're occuring

Tags: python, ffmpeg, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

This is the output for when I feed flac files into Google's Speech Recognition API. It says that if starts and finishes most of the files but then it gives me these errors when it nears the end. I have checked and all these files are native flac files. I took out a good chunk of the output above "source/out70.flac started" becuase it's all the same besides the file number.

```
source/out70.flac started
source/out25.flac started
source/out17.flac done
source/out18.flac started
source/out25.flac done
source/out20.flac done
source/out21.flac started
source/out10.flac done
source/out100.flac started
source/out14.flac done
source/out18.flac done
source/out21.flac done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 203, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 129, in initfp
    self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 208, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.initfp(file_object)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 314, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 234, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(aiff_file, "rb")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 917, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\aifc.py", line 314, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio_GoogleAPI_Python\fast.py", line 92, in <module>
    all_text = pool.map(transcribe, enumerate(files))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio_GoogleAPI_Python\fast.py", line 82, in transcribe
    with sr.AudioFile(name) as source:
  File "C:\Users\hmkur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 236, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

Comment: EOFError is raised when `input()` or `raw_input()` do not read any data before the end of the `InputStream` is reached. So could it be that you are "inputting" more flac files than you realy have or are some corrupted?

Comment: @Strohhut yeah thank you! I was inputting empty flac files, I changed the code so instead of generating a set number of files, it only generates as many as needed